# Likert-normality and multiple regression assumptions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, multiple-regression, likert

I have a questions measured through Likert scale (1-5)

Independent variables:
I believe xx is a problem        strongly disagree(1)  disag   neutral agree s-agree(5)

I believe yy is a problem        strongly disagree(1)  disag   neutral agree s-agree(5)

Dependent variable
xyz       (1,2,3)  ---not a binary

I am planning to run some tests.

I found there are lots of debate on parametric vs non parametric on it.

Some test needs normality. What about normality test in this case? Do I need to carry out normality test on Likert scale.Or is it logical?

but lets suppose that in question 1, most of the respondents agree that xx is a problem(4 or 5), so how would data be a normal distributed? obviously it will be skewed(right).

So does normality make sense in it? (unless the result is kind of neutral).
I saw lots of debates going on but for an academic research what can i do? (Likert scale score vs category score or continuous and so on)

Since my dependent variable is not binary, I am planning use multiple regression(cannot use logistic regression, but log regression is much lenient on assumptions), but problem is for some reasons my all questions replies are not meeting the criteria for multiple regression (especially normality of data, and standard residual).

so what kind of do? Is it needed to carry out all assumption test to run multiple regression on likert scale question?

What may be my options(to predict or test the hypothesis)?

thank you

Comment: 1. Likert items are plainly not normal https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=normality+likert -- there would be no point in testing something you already know for sure... however  2. IVs *are not assumed to be normal* in regression. 3. Your DV is not normal either (though it's not the raw/marginal DV that is assumed to be normal), not even close. You don't state what the 1,2,3 values represent -- is that categorical? Ordered categorical? A count? Likely-to-be-suitable models for each of those cases are discussed in posts on site already. Please clarify the nature of your DV.

Comment: thanks for your comments. DV is categorical, 0=not present,1=low presence,2=high presence. I also found that there is something called orginal regression, what may be good in my case. I am trying to take IV1,IV2 and trying to test effect on DV(hypothesis).

Comment: Please edit that additional (critical) information into your question (and also change "screwed" to "skewed" in the question). That would be ordinal regression rather than orginal, and yes, that might be a good choice for a DV with ordered categories, depending on what you're trying to find out. What is the actual question you're trying to answer? (in plain words, avoid any hint of statistical jargon please)

Comment: my hypothesis is:
A factor(IV-multivariate) is positively related to intention to use something(DV).

Comment: HOW many IVs or factors you have ? What are your question items?

Comment: IV-8, each is a multi-variate construct i.e.
IV1
    question-1 about iv1
question-2 about iv1
IV2
  question-1 about iv2
question-2 about iv2
and so on

Comment: Reporting of data and objectives could help people respond your questions. You talk about counts . Low presence ?  Parametric vs. Non-parametric tests and relation-based hypothesis and assumptions and want to determine factors that influence DV. You may exhibit data. Edit your question to enable a correct understanding of your problem. A vague question can not be answered adequately. A reading of multiple regression, multi-variate analysis and the underlying assumption alongwith understanding of linear combination of variables may be useful before you edit your question.

Comment: I am changing hypothesis like:  "A factor is positively (co)-related to something use." and research question is: what factors are co-related to something use? (show negative-positive). I think i can use multiple or ordinal regression now. Isn't it?

Comment: No ! See my comment at the bottom of  my Answer. Bipolar responses can not be rated like the ratings  you have given I.e. 1-5. It is illogical. Hence, you should correct first of all scoring. Further it does not seem to me  a  reasonable approach to use binomial or multinomial DV  and continuous or rank data as Independent variables. If you presume  that your DV scoring (1,2,3 as edited) is taken as continuous measure and IVs measured on a continuous scale , you can do ordinary multiple-regression. I do not know wwhether you are working on real data.  your level of research - prePhd or m.phil.